# is that repetitive use of Android Shared Preference storage make effect on performance?

Tags: android, sharedpreferences, android-sharedpreferences

My application using LocationListener in Android Service to get frequent locations updated. Application have some location filter related  data stored in shared preference. Requirement is to get frequent location updates as possible as.
I retrive data from Shared Preference in onLocationChanged of the listeners. 
This is my code

```
public class MyLocationListener implements LocationListener {
    public void onLocationChanged(final Location loc) {
        sharedPreferences =  PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getApplicationContext());
        int filterOne = sharedPreferences.getInt("filter_data",100);
        ------
        ------
        //code to process location with filter   
        ------
        ------ 
    }
}
```

Using above code sharedPreference is used in repetitive manner.

I already tried place filter variables in outside of onLocationChanged, but when service is restarted the values lost and set to zero.

I just want to know is that good practice or not?
Should I have to use another option?

Comment: If the value is lost, just put if(sharedPreferences == null) then initialize it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Using above code sharedPreference is used in repetitive manner. I just want to know is that good practice or not?

Accessing SharedPreferences in a repetitive manner is no problem. However in your case you are reinitializing `sharedPreferences` everytime the event fires. You should just do that once, in the `onCreate` of your activity or the `onCreateView` of your fragment.

Same applies to `filterOne`. If that value is constant, as in it doesn't change, you should only retrieve it once, outside of the `onLocationChanged` call.

---

So to answer your question

> is that repetitive use of Android Shared Preference storage make effect on performance?

Yes, but only because you reinitialize it every time. If you follow my advice there will be little to no impact on performance.

Comment: Too many people miss the impact of initialising objects that are reused, good answer!

Comment: @Tim Castelijns, I tried place it in onCreate, but when service is restart the values are lost.

Comment: @AMY, if you are using a service, the same logic applies, however you should place it in the service's `onCreate`, or in its `onBind` method

Comment: @Tim Castelijns, onBind get called every time service get started? restarted by system, basically when I closed app?

Comment: @AMY onBind is called when an activity or similar binds itself to the service. onCreate is called when the service is created.

Comment: @Tim Castelijns problem is service is restarted on application close and all filter variables are set to zero, onCreate and onStartCommand is not getting called. Please assist.

Comment: @AMY you can do the initialization in the onBind() and (re)bind yourself to the service when the app is resumed/restarted